# How can I enable Hoefler Text Engraved set on Fontspec?

Tags: fontspec, hoefler

I am trying to enable the Engraved set that comes with Hoefler Text on a Mac, but cannot seem to make any headway.  Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra}
\setromanfont[Alternate=0]{Hoefler Text}

\begin{document}
ENGRAVED
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is that an AAT font? I don’t have a copy to test.

Comment: I checked the `.ttc` with FontForge and there is a lookup table at for engraved text `<19,1> Engraved Text lookup 7` but xelatex doesn't find it. I get the error: `Package fontspec Warning: AAT feature 'Style=Engraved' (19,2) not available in font 'Hoefler Text'.`

Comment: me too. when I attempt to simply paste an extended unicode glyph like ℂ (engraved font type of C, U+2102) into the Apple Pages LaTex eequation editor it says I can't use it, unrecognised. So looks like I need to go to the step of referencing one of the Engraved fonts on my system already.    

I'm wondering if there's a set of codes in LaTex for these as math symbols because they're commonly used in math. "Mathematics for Computer Science" (2018), Eric Lehman et al uses them on the second page.