# I wish to use "engraved font" type glyphs for set names e.g. , , ℂ, ,… (U+1D538 – U+2149) but struggling to find LaTex codes for them

Tags: fonts, symbols, unicode

Hopefully LaTex symbols exist for these "engraved font" type of Unicode glyphs for single letters of the alphabet [A-Z][a-z] which are included with many fonts in the Extended Unicode range.

These symbols are common in mathematics, [*Mathematics for Computer Science*](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring18/mcs.pdf) by Eric Lehman et al, (2018) has put them to use by the second page already.

Yet the Latex cheat sheets and intro webpages I've read so far make no mention of them, nor a search here other than a thread about using a specific font, Hoefler Text Engraved (which I guess is my backup plan if there are no existing glyph codes in LaTex)

e.g.

- -> U+1D539
- -> U+1D538
- ℂ -> U+2102

Unfortunately some of these letters like ℂ, ℙ & ℚ have a different font weight applied by default, but I'll live with that for now.

if there are no LaTex codes, what method should I use to reference one of the "Engraved" style fonts installed on my system, and can

Comment: Welcome! So you don't mean blackboard fonts?

Comment: Please link when you reference another post. The search function sucks.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542356/how-can-i-enable-hoefler-text-engraved-set-on-fontspec, maybe? Note that if you are using Apple Pages's equation editor and if that uses MathJax or similar (as is likely), your question is off-topic for this site as MathJax has nothing to do with TeX, even though the syntax is similar.

Comment: Try Stix2   they have engraved symbols. by the way my 2004 Lehman book does not use them or I missed them.

Comment: @cfr it's literally the only "Hoefler Text Engraved" in the LaTex stack… but I'd moved away from it when I composed this post so didn't bother. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542356/how-can-i-enable-hoefler-text-engraved-set-on-fontspec

Comment: While I'm using Pages equation editor at present, quite happy to change, I'll end up composing my paper in InDesign and previously have composed equations in Illustrator (for decades) which is perfectly postscript pleasant to look at, but the endless tweaking of positions/scales/styles ends up laboriously slow to complete. I've used web-based LaTex composition apps in the past IIRC?!? 

Also, the Latex cheat sheet  I'm using (https://quickref.me/latex) has worked for my efforts in Pages so far, but I'm doing dead simple stuff, absolute beginner here! Happy to move to another tool/INDD plugin

Comment: noting that in MathJax it is possible to define LaTeX commands as you do in your TeX files.  "It's enough to insert something like

$ \newcommand{\SES}[3]{ 0 \to #1 \to #2 \to #3 \to 0 } $
 at the top of your post (remember the dollars!). Then you can just use your commands as you are used to do: in my example typing  $$ \SES{A}{B}{C} $$ will produce the following: 0→→→→0 " 
--source: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11638/343777

Comment: yes, @cfr, I did mean Blackboard glyphs/fonts, just didn't know that's what I meant ;-)

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil Which illustrates the problem. You should NOT use `$$ ... $$` for maths in LaTeX. You should use `\[ ... \]` or `equation` or one of the `amsmath`/`mathtools` environments. Nor can I think of a case where it would be good practice to use `$\newcommand...` in *any* TeX format. MathJax is fundamentally different. It is not TeX and you can't define LaTeX commands in it. They may look similar, but they aren't LaTeX. MathJaX doesn't use TeX period. If you use a web-based app like Overleaf, that is, of course, LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blackboard fonts?

[image: ABC in blackboard]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$
  \mathbb{ABC}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess maybe you want a sans version. I should probably delete this.

Comment: I'll take what I can get for the present time. That's reasonable for my needs, san serif nice to have if it's an option.